# Magento 2 - How to make a customer attribute required in admin_checkout form only

Tags: magento2, attributes, customer

Magento 2 -  How to make a customer attribute required in admin_checkout form only

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have achieved it using adding css classes, since it's in admin section so adding required css classes did the job.

Comment: ok.greats. If you want to post the  answer, then please do